# OAuthProblem, missing parameter access_token

Tags: java, facebook, oauth, authorization

I'm getting this error while trying to get an access token for a user. This has to do with the authorization process of a facebook application. The code that produces that exception is the following:

```
OAuthClientRequest oAuthRequest = OAuthClientRequest
    .tokenLocation("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token")
    .setGrantType(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
    .setClientId("myAppId")
    .setClientSecret("myAppSecret")
    .setRedirectURI("myAppURL").setCode(code)
    .buildBodyMessage();
```

And the exception thrown follows beneath:

```
12:14:22,468 ERROR [STDERR] OAuthProblemException{description='Missing parameters:   
access_token', error='invalid_request', uri='null', state='null', scope='null'}
12:14:22,468 ERROR [STDERR]     
at org.apache.amber.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthProblemException.error(OAuthProblemException.java:57)
12:14:22,468 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.amber.oauth2.common.utils.OAuthUtils.handleOAuthProblemException(OAuthUtils.java:165)
12:14:22,468 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.amber.oauth2.common.utils.OAuthUtils.handleMissingParameters(OAuthUtils.java:183)
12:14:22,468 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.amber.oauth2.client.validator.OAuthClientValidator.validateRequiredParameters(OAuthClientValidator.java:90)
12:14:22,468 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.amber.oauth2.client.validator.OAuthClientValidator.validateParameters(OAuthClientValidator.java:53)
12:14:22,468 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.amber.oauth2.client.validator.OAuthClientValidator.validate(OAuthClientValidator.java:49)
12:14:22,468 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.amber.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.validate(OAuthClientResponse.java:61)
12:14:22,468 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.amber.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.init(OAuthClientResponse.java:56)
12:14:22,468 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.amber.oauth2.client.response.OAuthAccessTokenResponse.init(OAuthAccessTokenResponse.java:52)
12:14:22,468 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.amber.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponseFactory.createCustomResponse(OAuthClientResponseFactory.java:60)
12:14:22,468 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.amber.oauth2.client.URLConnectionClient.execute(URLConnectionClient.java:105)
12:14:22,468 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.amber.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:58)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at tpc.facebook.autenticacion.ServletOAuth2.obtenerCodeYAccessToken(ServletOAuth2.java:315)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at tpc.facebook.autenticacion.ServletOAuth2.doGet(ServletOAuth2.java:217)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)1
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
12:14:22,469 ERROR [STDERR] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the normal OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse:

```
OAuthAccessTokenResponse oAuthResponse = oAuthClient.accessToken(request);
```

my problem is, Facebook responds with

```
OAuthProblemException{description='null', error='{"message":"Error validating verification code.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}', uri='null', state='null', scope='null'}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I got it to work! Problem was: the redirect url must be the same for every oauth request... then it works. forget the thing about the OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse. using the GitHubTokenResponse is necessary

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem implementing the client and the server, the problem is about one mistake in the Client Example in the Apache Amber (Oltu) project:

First you have the Auth code request (which work):

```
OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest
 .authorizationLocation(AUTHORIZE_URL)
 .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
 .setRedirectURI(REDIR_URL)
 .setResponseType(CODE_RESPONSE)
 .**buildQueryMessage**();
```

And second the request about the Access Token (which don't work):

```
OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest
  .tokenLocation(ACCESS_TOKEN_URL)
  .setGrantType(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
  .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
  .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
  .setRedirectURI(REDIR_URL)
  .setCode(code)
  .**buildBodyMessage**();
```

The mistake is about the buildBodyMessage() in the second request. Change it by buildQueryMessage().

Enjoy :)

Comment: Could you please guide on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001135/apache-oltu-instragram-integration-doesnt-return-access-token-why ?